# How to change OS HP mini netbook

Tags: netbook

I have a new hp mini 110-1109nr and would like to change the OS from XP to either Win7 or Ubuntu. However, the BIOS doesn't show boot from USB as an option (only HD and network-boot).
Does anyone know if it's possible to enable USB booting? Do I need to update the firmware?
Is it hard to net-boot? (I have a spare machine w/ Linux I can use a host).
Can I install from the HD if I create a partition?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

plug in your USB device, turn on the HP Mini and hit F9 when the POST screen (HP logo) appears, this will bring up the boot selection menu.

Comment: Older BIOS used to show the USB port as a bootable device without anything plugged in, so I just assumed this was still the case.

Answer (score 1):

In my experience, PXE boot is troublesome. You should focus on booting from an USB-pen.

To create a bootable pen with Ubuntu (or some other free operating system) use [UNetbootin](http://unetbootin.sourceforge.net/). Just download it and follow the on-screen instructions. It couldn't be any easier. I have no experience with Windows installation from USB pens.

When booting from USB you must have a bootable device attached or the option will not show in BIOS / boot selection menu.

Comment: Good point about plugging in the device *before* booting. I'm guessing that the OP assumed because it wasn't listed in the absence of the device, it wouldn't be possible.